# How to determine if issue crash from Crashlytics list is classified as OOM

Tags: ios, crashlytics

From Crashlytics dashboard I observing rising amount of out of memory (OOM) crashes for app and together with this also amout of crashes for one issue increased, however if I open this crash I can't see information that this was clarified as OOM... Is this possible to check this with that way?

Answer (score -1):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

OOMs are not included in your crash reports, and they're separated from crash statistics like crash-free users. The percentage report of OOMs that you see in your dashboard does not have corresponding crash reports like normal crashes.

The reason is that OOMs are inherently difficult to capture. iOS doesn't have any mechanisms for capturing and recording OOM terminations, so Fabric has to use some heuristics to identify when an OOM occurred, and there's no stacktrace that comes along with it.

If you're seeing your OOM rate increase and only one particular issue spike in activity, it seems possible you introduced a change that increased the frequency of that particular issue as well as increasing the frequency of OOMs. I would check the "free RAM" portion of your crash reports for that issue, as that will also give you insight into the memory state of the device at crash time.

Also, check out these links for some more information on Fabric OOM reporting:
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/OOMs.html
https://fabric.io/blog/2016/08/17/introducing-oom-reporting/